# How to Conditionally Fill Pandas Column based on Cell Values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of around 10000 rows and want to fill multiple columns based on certain conditions.

if Operating System Contains "Windows Server" , so Platform takes server or contains ('Windows 7|Windows 10') than Platform takes "Workstation"

Code I Have Tried:

```
conditions = [
    (dfADTM['Operating System'].str.contains('Windows Server')),
    (dfADTM['Operating System'].str.contains('Windows 10|Windows 7|Windows XP')),
    (dfADTM['Operating System'].str.contains('Cisco|SLES|OnTap|unknown'))]
choices = ['Server', 'Workstation', 'Network Appliance']
dfADTM['Platform AD'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Check')
print(dfADTM.head())
```

Error I am facing :

```
[Running] python -u "c:\Users\Abhinav Kumar\Desktop\weekly\code.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Abhinav Kumar\Desktop\weekly\code.py", line 36, in <module>
    dfADTM['Platform AD'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Check')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 715, in select
    'invalid entry {} in condlist: should be boolean ndarray'.format(i))
ValueError: invalid entry 0 in condlist: should be boolean ndarray

[Done] exited with code=1 in 7.725 seconds
```

The Resulting dataframe expected is:
[image: Dataframe]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas conditional creation of a series/dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: Checking the link

Comment: Please post the actual source code or printed output rather than links

Comment: @Chris , shared the actual code

Comment: @HenryYik - that is helpful but does not solves the problem as the conditions need to be boolean and I have a case where if string contains a word or not.

Comment: `str.contains` returns a boolean array. It is unclear why you get the error - perhaps you have something other than `string` in your column `Operating System`. Use `dfADTM['Operating System'].str.contains('Windows Server', na=False)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**Not an efficient method but will get the job done**

```
df.index

for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['OS'][i].split(" ")[1]=='Server':
      df.set_value(i, 'Platform', 'Server')
    if df['OS'][i].split(" ")[1]=='7' or df['OS'][i].split(" ")[1]=='10':
      df.set_value(i, 'Platform', 'Workstation')
```

you can drop the index or reset it if you want to

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :
`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['Platform']=np.nan #create an empty column in the dataframe
for i in range(len(df)):
        a=df['Operating System'][i]
        if ('Windows 10' or 'Windows 7' or 'Windows XP')  in a:
            df['Platform'][i]='Workstation'
        elif ('Cisco' or 'SLES' or 'OnTap' or 'unknown') in a:
            df['Platform'][i]='Network Appliance'
        elif ('Windows Server') in a:
            df['Platform'][i]='Server'
        else:
            df['Platform'][i]='Not mentioned' #For the values which do no fall into any category
`
```